# How to fetch User object for each id in Flowable<List<String>>

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a Flowable of a List of ids that represent user ids in a group.

```
private val memberIdsFlowable: Flowable<List<String>> = groupFlowable
        .map { it.members }
```

I need to call

```
fun fetchUserFlowable(id: String): Flowable<User>
```

For each id in the list and combine them to a list of users `Flowable<List<User>>`

What I've tried is this:

```
private val membersFlowable = memberIdsFlowable
    .concatMap { list ->
        Flowable.fromIterable(list)
            .map { userRepository.fetchUserFlowable(it) }
    }
```

But it results in `Flowable<Flowable<User>>` rather than `Flowable<List<User>>` and if I add `toList()` operator then it's a type mismatch :

```
   private val membersFlowable = memberIdsFlowable
    .concatMap { list ->
        Flowable.fromIterable(list)
            .map { userRepository.fetchUserFlowable(it) }
            .toList()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need `concatMap` inside as well:

```
private val membersFlowable = memberIdsFlowable
    .concatMap { list ->
        Flowable.fromIterable(list)
            .concatMap { userRepository.fetchUserFlowable(it) }
    }
```

So that the lambda returns `Flowable<User>` for each `list`.

EDIT: if you want one `List<User>` for each `List<String>` in `memberIdsFlowable`, the outer operation should be `map`. I am less sure about its argument, but I think something like this should work:

```
private val membersFlowable = memberIdsFlowable
    .map { list ->
        Flowable.fromIterable(list)
            .concatMap { userRepository.fetchUserFlowable(it) }
            .toList()
    }
```

Comment: But the `membersFlowable` now is of type `Flowable<User>` when I need it to be `Flowable<List<User>>`.

Maybe I explained it poorly, basically I need to convert `memberIdsFlowable : Flowable<List<String>>` to `Flowable<List<User>>` with my `fun fetchUserFlowable(id: String): Flowable<User>`

Comment: `toList()` returns a `Single<List<T>>`, so the outer operation should be `concatMapSingle` (or `switchMapSingle`) instead of `map`.